# NR Deluxe support or alternitives?

Tags: windows-mobile

I have a Palm Treo 700wx, and I currently have a Novii Remote Deluxe trial
I am looking for support to get continued support for it as I only have 8 days left on it

I can't find a way to reset the timer as I can't find it in the regestry and i've deleted the config file, AND uninstalled and reinstalled it, to no avail

I have tried contacting Novii, but they're extinct, even the people that currently own their domain [novii.tv](http://novii.tv) haven't even kept it filled, it's devoid of links

I'm just wanting to use it as a remote, but don't want to change the time to trick it as I use it for my clock throughout the day.

for any mods that think this is off topic, it's not, if anything Win 8/10 phone as they aren't even mentioned, questions are read the sub title of it's Area 51 page [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20757?phase=commitment)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question relating to a Windows Phone device

Comment: @RowlandShaw actually this  area is actually in the right spot as in Area 51, and it's normal description says that it is for both Windows Phone and Windows Mobile devices, the latter of which is my Palm,Windows Mobile 5

Comment: The Area 51 page is [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20757/windows-phone) and also it says in it's sub title `Beta Q&A site for enthusiasts and power users of Windows Mobile and Windows Phone 7.`, in theory with this info, all the people asking about Windows 8 and 10 insider preview are actually off-topic as they aren't even mentioned

Comment: [That's what I said back in 2012](http://meta.windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/13/106), however consensus was otherwise back then, and if anything my opinion has wavered the other way, since no new devices with Windows Mobile have been made available in the intervening period.

Comment: @Rowland Shaw Could you recommend somewhere I could put this then? this seems the best place as it was originally made for things like this

Comment: @RowlandShaw, you could technicallyput it on hold for dealing with programs, because they constantly change, even though nobody had devoloped it since 2013 (that's the newest thing I could find)

Comment: @RowlandShaw, you should ask on the Meta to see if others agree with you before you just say "not today"

Comment: The consensus on meta 5 years ago was that Windows Mobile is off topic - nothing has changed since then that would change that opinion, and as I said before, it may well only strengthen that consensus. If you feel the situation has changed, why not raise that in [meta](http://meta.windowsphone.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @RowlandShaw, I only have 1 rep, I can't meta here yet

Comment: @RowlandShaw, Where would this go then? This is the only place where WM people are more available than say, Think Differently or SuperUser

Comment: @DanHolli I gave you an upvote so you can participate on meta. But for the record, I also don't believe Windows Mobile questions should be on topic here. Yes, the original pitch on Area 51 may have included it, but that was 5 years ago (and even then Windows Mobile was already deprecated). As for where to go with your question, I think the [/r/windowsphone](https://www.reddit.com/r/windowsphone) subreddit allows WM questions.